# WampServer mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, wampserver

I have a mySQL database problem - I'm a newbie to this: 
I've installed WAMP Server and I'm able to log into localhost then phpmyadmin to give the screen below (right image). But I get No *xNo Privileges* in red -- I see from online examples that I should see "Create new database":
[image]
Suggestions are welcome.
[I have no password and the login is just 'local']

Comment: 'local' probably wasn't setup with correct privileges. Login as 'root' and make changes from there (don't do this on a production environment, but it's fine when done locally)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this message because you have `made up` a userid and password.

MySQL's initial installation state has ONE userid defined called `root`. 
This is the case regardless of how you installed MySQL, unless the install asks you for a password at installation time.

That is the `SUPER USER` and can do anything.
By default (again which ever way you install MySQL) this `root` user has no password.

So login to phpMyAdmin using :-

```
username = root
password = (leave this blank, empty)

Press the Login button.
```

You will now be loged in as root.

PS.
Its a good idea to add a password to this username, BUT PLEASE DONT FORGET IT, as recovery can be a pain.